# Installing ASP .NET packages made for older versions of .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, nuget

I'm attempting to use the [Jdenticon.AspNet.WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jdenticon.AspNet.WebApi/) nuget package in my project. My project uses Target Framework `.NET 6.0`. From what I can tell, the `Jdenticon.AspNet.WebApi` package doesn't support `.NET 6.0`? However, the [Jdenticon website](https://jdenticon.com/#supported-platforms) says that `ASP.NET WebApi 4.0+` is supported.

When I try to use the package in my Minimal API Project, I get the following error:

```
Assembly 'Jdenticon.AspNet.WebApi' with identity 'Jdenticon.AspNet.WebApi, Version=3.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3fcf9f6e3475a4f8' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http' with identity 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

My question is, is it possible to use a package like this that was built for an older version(?) of .NET?

Comment: In a word no. The listed dependencies are only for .NET Framework 4.5 which won't work for a .NET 6 project. Now, if the package also listed a .NET Standard you might have a chance.

Comment: However all is not lost here. The [quick start guide for ASP.NET Core](https://jdenticon.com/#quick-start-asp-net-core) states that you should `Install-Package Jdenticon.AspNetCore` which is a completely different package which support .NET Framework 4.5.1, .NET Standard 1.6 and .NET Standard 2.1.

Comment: @phuzi it is possible to use packages for .net framework in .net core+ applications. It will not work if the package uses any of the removed APIs. But it should work if the package only contains logic. For the specific package in question I have no idea if it will work or not, easiest way to tell is probably to test. But you are completely right that `Jdenticon.AspNetCore` should be used instead.

Comment: .net core is NOT the same as .net framework. Code is very similar, and in most cases you not notice the difference. Introduction of .net framework library and assemblies into .net core framework is a VERY bad idea if as such can be avoided. So, don't confuse .net framework with .net core - they are different, and the major difference is that .net core has windows OS dependencies removed, which results (in theory) that such code can run on any platform. Introduction of net framework into .net core is a big choice and means you are dependent on .net framework, and adopting .net framework also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the other comments and answers, I found that the package I was trying to use, `Jdenticon.AspNet.WebApi`, was made for .NET, and not .NET Core, which was what my project was. My ultimate solution was to just not use this package.

More specifically in regards to my problem, I found that all I needed was the base [Jdenticon-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jdenticon-net/3.1.2) package.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that you are already using `System.Web.Http`. But the version you are using is `4.0`, while the library you are installing require version `5.0`. Since these are different mayor versions there is no guarantee about backward compatibility, so nuget will not update the library automatically, since it could result in compilation errors.

So go into nuget and update `System.Web.Http` to version `5.0`. If you are lucky you will not have any errors, but you might need to fix some minor issues like namespaces or similar. If you are really unlucky there are major incompatible changes that forces you to reconsider the update, so make sure you commit any changes before starting, so you have a good point to return to if there are issues.

You could also see if there is any older version of the package that uses the `4.0` version. I would not trust the website, since it could easily be outdated.

But the best solution is probably to use a library specifically for .net core+, i.e.  `Jdenticon.AspNetCore`.

This does not really have anything to do with .Net 6 vs .net framework. But there might be other issues, there is no guarantee that a .net framework package will work in .net 6.